# wkhtmltopdf pages pushed down when I tried generate multiple pages inside a loop

Tags: margin, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf, asp.net-mvc-views

I'm tring to generae PDF from MVC view in .NET Core using Rotativa Library.
Everything works fine only issue is when I use Foreach in my view to replicate pages. It automatically gets margin and after few pages content pushed down which disturbs alignment.
This my style for page

```
.page {
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 372mm;
    page-break-after: always;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media print {
    
    .page {
        margin: 0px !important;
        padding: 0px !important;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: hidden; 
        page-break-after: always; 
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
}
```

this is my markup code

```
 @foreach (var form in Model.Inspections)
        {
            <div class="page" >
            <p>TEST</p>
            </div>
        }
```

I hvae tried different solution but nothing is working. If I remove this css
page-break-after: always;
it will add empty blank page after each report page and in this scenario pages don't push down.
I also tried to give negative top margin in interation but this also not works well.

Kindly help me on this one if someone faced the same problem.